# MediaWiki: Automatic font color change to wiki-specific colors

Tags: fonts, colors, mediawiki

Is it possible to make the font color change to the wiki-specific default text (or default color of links) automatically?

For example, you want to define font color with the font tag, and you insert a value that causes the font color to automatically change to the text (or link) color of the wiki.

Something like this: `<font color="the mysterious value">This text will appear in the default link color of this wiki.</font>`

Comment: Do you want this to happen everywhere on the site, or only where you put this font tag?

Answer (score 2):

The link color is set by a [CSS rule](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/master/skins/common/commonElements.css) that looks something like this:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0645ad;
    background: none;
}
```

Since this rule applies only to `a` elements (i.e. links), the only way (short of JavaScript trickery) to make it *automatically* apply to a given piece of text on any wiki is to actually wrap that piece of text in a link.  Sorry.

That said, if you just want a piece of text that has a different color on different wikis, that's easy — just wrap it in a `span` element, give the `span` a custom class name, and add a CSS rule to [your wiki's site stylesheet (Common.css)](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCSS) defining what color the text should have, like this:

**HTML (on wiki page):**

```html
<span class="mysterious">This text will appear in a color defined in this
wiki's site stylesheet.</span>
```

**CSS (in Common.css):**

```css
span.mysterious {
    color: #0645ad;  /* make it look like a link */
}
```

That way, if you copy the page to a different wiki with different CSS, the text will look different.